# How can I connect a Jupyter Notebook to a remote MySQL DB using Peewee?

Tags: mysql, database, authentication, jupyter-notebook, peewee

I am trying Peewee to connect and retrieve data from a MySQL remote database, but I get the following error:

> InternalError: (1130, "Host 'x.x.x.x' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server")

Could you help me?

Comment: Peewee is an orm how would it connect?

Comment: I'll need a bit more of your use case to help you choose the best way. Is this a test, a real production project, just for your use or for the use of many ? Why do you need to connect a mysql db ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "retrieve data from a MySQL remote database"
>
> "Host is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server"

Seem to point on a simple problem:

**You're not allowed to connect on the DB from "outside".**

---

By default, MySql / MariaDB are only listening on the "inside" of the server, from [MariaDb doc](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/configuring-mariadb-for-remote-client-access/) :

> MariaDB packages bind MariaDB to 127.0.0.1 (the loopback IP address) by default as a security measure using the bind-address configuration directive.

This mean apart for an application that run on the same machine (accessing `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`), you'll not be able to connect.

---

## Solutions:

### SSH tunnelling

This is probably the safest way to allow a connexion on a remote DB.

SSH is a protocol that allow you to connect to a server. It's mainly used on unix server to manage them, but can do a lot more.

How to use it in your case?

if you can [connect with SSH to your DB server](https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/connecting-mariadb-through-ssh-tunnel), then running this simple command on your notebook the will do the trick:

```
ssh -L 3306:localhost:3306 user@x.x.x.x
```

Lets explain a bit: first, your run SSH, then, you tell him to enable a port forwarding from your `3306` port to the `localhost:3306` port of the server you connect through `user@IP`.

With this command running, every query from your `local machine:3306` will by send to your `MariaDB:3306` server, allowing you to use it as if you where on the server.

### Allowing a remote-access user

This one is **way more dangerous than the previous one**. You'll need to take your time and **think about every outcome it mean**.

As already said, you're not allowed to connect from outside, ssh let you be "inside", but if you know what you do, you can just remove the security.

The point is:

- to make an account that'll be able to login from a remote IP,
- allow MariaDB to listen on external requests,
- and at least, secure other account to disable remote connection.

*[I'm not putting the how-to now, if you really need it, I'll update this answer]*